# Python expand integers inside a list and sort them

Tags: python

I have a list :

```
l = [[120,137],[112,119]]
```

I would like to expand the numbers and sort them... Expected output :

```
newl = [112, 113,....,119,120,121...,137]
```

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: Search this site for the word "flatten", then use `sorted` on the result.

Comment: @MarkRansom : Thanks for the keyword... looking more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it would be

```
>>> xx = []
>>> for x in l:
...   a, b = x[0], x[1]
...   xx += range(a, b+1)
... 
>>> xx
[120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]
>>> sorted(xx)
[112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137]
>>>
```

Or just (based on @wim's comment):

```
for a, b in l:
    xx += range(a, b+1)
```

Should be enough

Comment: +1, but you need to use `b+1` as the upper end of the ranges.

Comment: ah.. thank you so much.. I just noticed that myself too.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list_ = [[120,137],[112,119]]
>>> sorted(n for low, high in list_ for n in range(low, high + 1))
[112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137]
```

Comment: Indeed, I did miss that.

Comment: Yay. +1, even though I need to read this nested generator expression three times to understand it. And I still don't really understand it...:)

Comment: That's only fair, because I had to write it three times to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools    
>>> l = [[120,137],[112,119]]
>>> sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable([range(i[0],i[1]+1) for i in l]))
[112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137]
```